# R Shiny - modular - dynamic inputs in datatable - editable data table - issues with binding & displaying

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable

**Reproducible Example**

```
library(shiny)

apply_selectInput <- function(X) {
  paste0("selectInput(
    inputId = session$ns(",paste0("'type_input_",X[["row_name"]],"'"),"),
    label = NULL,
    choices = c('Other','Sports Car','Family Car'),
    selectize = FALSE
  )")
}

get_data <- function() {
  ## in mine, this is pulling in SQL data ##
  data <- as.data.frame(mtcars) %>%
    mutate(`Car Name` = rownames(mtcars))
  return(data)
}

get_data_w_inputs <- function(data = get_data()) {
  data$Type <- apply(
    X = data %>% mutate(row_name = rownames(data)),
    MARGIN = 1,
    FUN = apply_selectInput
  )
  return(data)
}

ui_function <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    dataTableOutput(outputId = ns('dt')),
    uiOutput(outputId = ns('ui'))
  )
}

server_function <- function(input,output,session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  ## The session$userData$vars is important
  ## it's storing the data in a global (ish?)
  ## environment - in my real script, the data
  ## is in one module and the datatable is in a
  ## different module - and I need to write back
  ## to the data based on the changes made in the
  ## datatable - so this makes me able to read &
  ## write to the data sources from all modules
  session$userData$vars <- reactiveValues(
    orig = get_data_w_inputs(),
    filtered = get_data_w_inputs(),
    changes = get_data_w_inputs(),
    inputs = NULL
  )
  
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      session$userData$vars$filtered %>% 
        mutate(Type = as.character(eval(parse(text = Type)))),
      rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(target = "cell"),
      fillContainer = T,
      extensions = c('Buttons'),
      options = list(
        searching = FALSE,
        paging = FALSE,
        dom = 'tB',
        scrollY = '500px',
        scrollCollapse = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    print(input)
  })
}

## dashboard UI ##
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = 'Test',
    controlbarIcon = shiny::icon("filter")
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
    
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    ui_function('datatable')
  )
)

## dashboard server ##
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## pull in modules ##
  callModule(server_function,'datatable')
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**Problem 1**
One issue is that when I add the binding callbacks to the datatable, the entire thing disappears; however, if you dig into the back-end/inspect, all the rows are still there, it's just that the height is set to 0.  I can create a CSS file/edit this manually, but I don't understand why it's doing this and wondering if there's a better way to keep this from happening in the first place.

**Problem 2**
The second issue is that the inputs are not actually binding to the namespace.  I've tried seven thousand things after digging through Stack Overflow and NOTHING. WORKS.  The closest I got was that the last row of the datatable's input was binding, but not all at the same time.  I've seen that most folks use a variety of apply when binding inputs from a dataframe, but when I do this, I get an error message saying it can't find the session.  I think this is because I have the functions separate from the module.  However, I need this - I actually make calls to these functions in several spots (getting the data initially to set up filters, saving the data & refreshing it) and I don't want to have to re-write this code every stinkin' time.

I've been told to look into the DTedit package; however, I see that's not a CRAN package and so I'd have to figure out how to tell my dockerfile to install it.  It also pulls up an entire editing form instead of editing in-table (correct?) which I do not want.

**Session Info**

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

apply_selectInput <- function(X) {
  paste0("selectInput(
    inputId = session$ns(",paste0("'type_input_",X[["row_name"]],"'"),"),
    label = NULL,
    choices = c('Other','Sports Car','Family Car'),
    selectize = FALSE
  )")
}

get_data <- function() {
  ## in mine, this is pulling in SQL data ##
  data <- as.data.frame(mtcars) %>%
    mutate(`Car Name` = rownames(mtcars)) 
  return(data)
}

get_data_w_inputs <- function(data = get_data()) {
  data$Type <- apply(
    X = data %>% mutate(row_name = gsub('\\s+', '', rownames(data))),
    MARGIN = 1,
    FUN = apply_selectInput
  )
  return(data)
}

ui_function <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    DTOutput(outputId = ns('dt')),
    uiOutput(outputId = ns('ui'))
  )
}

server_function  <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      sessionvars <- reactiveValues(
        orig = get_data_w_inputs(),
        filtered = get_data_w_inputs(),
        changes = get_data_w_inputs(),
        inputs = NULL
      )

      output$dt <- renderDT({
        df <- sessionvars$filtered %>%
          mutate(Type = as.character(eval(parse(text = Type ))))
        datatable(df, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE)},
          editable = list(target = "cell"),
          fillContainer = T,
          extensions = c('Buttons'),
          options = list(
            searching = FALSE,
            paging = FALSE,
            info = FALSE,
            dom = 'tB',
            scrollY = '500px',
            scrollCollapse = TRUE,
            fixedColumns = TRUE,
            autoWidth = TRUE,
            buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
            preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
            drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
          )
        
      )
      
      output$ui <- renderUI({
        print(input)
      })
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(ui_function('datatable'))

## dashboard server ##
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## pull in modules ##
  server_function('datatable')
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: The `session$userData$vars` is important - it's storing the data in a global (ish?) environment - in my real script, the data is in one module and the datatable is in a different module - and I need to write back to the data based on the changes made in the datatable - so this makes me able to read/write to the data sources from all modules

Comment: You can modify the variable name as necessary - `session$userData$vars`.  I didn't see a need in this MRE.

Comment: I didn't see any other changes besides that, though?? ... was there something else you changed?

Comment: where you close the `datatable()`, so that callback is effective.

Comment: Please run the code and confirm if the issues you noted are resolved.

Comment: Also, please see changes to `server_funtion()` module at the beginning.  No need to use `call module()` in the server, instead directly call as `server_function('datatable')`.

Comment: the code runs, but the inputs are still not binding to the session

Comment: I guess, I am not clear on your issue.  I think It works fine for me.  Please clarify what "not binding" means for you.

Comment: when this part runs `output$ui <- renderUI({ print(input) })`, it prints the inputs into your console - do you see all the inputs it's creating listed out?  Can you grab `input[['type_input_1']]` or does it give you an error?  I want to be able to read the value from the input

Comment: I cannot - I don't see the inputs in `print(input)` and I get an error message when I try to grab the value saying it doesn't exist ... so it's not binding the inputs to the session